# What format is a jQuery ajax post request sending the data in and how can it be accessed through Flask's request object?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, jqxhr

I am creating a web page that sends an XHR AJAX request using jQuery's $.post() object. The post is being received by a Flask app that is on another domain. The Javascript is below:

```
$.post('http://myurl.com/create', {
     'title': sender.title,
      'url': sender.url
});
```

The applicable Flask router code is:

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def create():
    print(request.args.get('title'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        url = request.form['url']

        new_mark = Mark(
            title=title,
            url=url
        )
        new_mark.save()

        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The Python is working great when a form is submitted to the url, but not when I POST through jQuery's AJAX object. It throws a 400 error every time I try to make the AJAX request. I looked at Flask's request.args object, but that has nothing in it when the request is made.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can check the logged requests in your browser's network tab

Comment: To post cross-domain, your Flask app needs to implement CORS. CORS requests from IE are not supported by jQuery because IE implements it's own object for cross-domain requests. There are jQuery extensions that try to implement it though.

Comment: I would suggest moving to a JSONP (GET) if at all possible.

Comment: Ok... @KevinB I found https://gist.github.com/1346220 and tried implementing that like '@app.route('/createcross', methods=['POST'])
def createcross(data):
    response = make_response(data)` but when I try that it throws an error that createcross() takes exactly one argument, but 0 are given... any ideas?

Comment: The jQuery side of it looks fine, i don't know enough about python or flask to help with that side of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Ajax request is not configured to target cross domain requests.
I suggest the use of $.ajax instead of $.post for more flexibility and to set crossDomain: true in your request configuration.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://myurl.com/create',
  crossDomain: true,
  data: '{'title': sender.title, 'url': sender.url}',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // Success Callback
  },
  error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Error Callback
  }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: setting cross-domain to true alone doesn't make cross-domain requests work. In the documentation, that option is for making a *same domain* request perform as if it were cross-domain, for example, a same-domain jsonp request. Since it is a cross-domain request, it already is true.

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid. I was not actually sending any data because sender.url and sender.title did not contain any values -_-.